# Boid animation in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to do a boid animation in python, but it does not animate.

First I'm setting an environment for boids - 2D box with dimentions `L x L`. The box in reality is a torus - the boid flying beyond right edge of the box flies in from left edge etc.

Positions of boids are randomly set from `0` to `L`, the angles are also randomly set from `0` to `2*pi`. The angles of velocity vectors indicate colours of the arrows.

For now, the boids are supposed to fly straight ahead, but it seems `animation` gives me a figure of overlapped first two frames.

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as scp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

#GLOBAL VARS
L   = 32
N   = 10
V_0 = 1

boid_pos  = L*np.random.rand(2, N)
boid_angl = 2*scp.pi*np.random.rand(N)

def displacement(x, angl):
    x_1 = x[0] + V_0*np.cos(angl)
    x_2 = x[1] + V_0*np.sin(angl)
    return np.vstack((x_1,x_2))

def check_bound(x):
    x = np.where(x > L,  x % L, x)
    x = np.where(x < 0, -x % L, x)
    return x

def evolution(t, x, angl, q, ax):
    x = displacement(x, angl)
    x = check_bound(x)
    q = ax.quiver(x[0], x[1], np.cos(angl), np.sin(angl), angl)
    return q
    
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
q = ax.quiver(boid_pos[0], boid_pos[1], np.cos(boid_angl), np.sin(boid_angl), boid_angl)

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, evolution, fargs=(boid_pos, boid_angl, q, ax),
                               frames = np.arange(0,100,1), interval = 50)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The figure I get:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't sure about your logic, so I customized the quiver sample from the official reference to animate it. The variable i to be looped is set to 30 times which is set in Frames. The value drawn by the variable i is changed. This is not a very good example, but I think it will help you understand the basic structure.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
# from IPython.display import HTML
from matplotlib.animation import PillowWriter

X = np.arange(-10, 10, 1)
Y = np.arange(-10, 10, 1)
U, V = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 10), ylim=(0, 10))
q = ax.quiver([], [], [], [])
# ax.quiverkey(q, X=0.3, Y=1.1, U=10, label='Quiver key, length = 10', labelpos='E')

def animate(i):
    X = np.arange(-i, i+1, 1)
    Y = np.arange(-i, i+1, 1)
    U, V = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
    q = ax.quiver(X, Y, U, V)
    return q

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=30, interval=200)
anim.save('quiver_ani.gif', writer='pillow')
# fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]